# Get hWnd for XAML control in Windows 8 (Metro) app?

Tags: windows, xaml, interop, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I need to pass a hwnd to a native dll that is going to write raw video to the frame.  In WPF this works because you can get a hwnd reference from a control.  Is this possible in a Metro app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get HWND for a control, because Metro doesn't have HWNDs.

If you can get the video stream, try using a video brush and setting the source.
Otherwise, look into SharpDx library, which is a managed port of DirectX. I think you can draw 'stuff' to an element from it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Metro doesn't have HWNDs." The main frame window technically does (Microsoft Spy++ shows a registered window class of "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow"), but yes, for individual controls that is true.